# How to know the files that are the most included in a project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2019, precompiled-headers

I am trying to fasten the build by using precompiled headers. I wonder what is the easiest/fastest way to know which files I should include in my "stdafx.h" so that they only build once?

Right now, I iterate over every file, and collect the #include section into one container for all files. Then, I manually count which file is included and how many times, finally I pick the relatively highest counted files and put them in "stdafx.h".

It works, but this is time consuming and I have many projects. Please and thank you.

Comment: I just put third party libraries and system headers there and avoid my own code unless I know its a header that I will not likely have to edit in the future.

Comment: @drescherjm So what is the problem with adding the headers that get changed often?

Comment: You end up making your builds take longer instead of shorter because the precompiled header needs to be regenerated after the change. It also forces more files to rebuild.

Comment: @drescherjm So I am doing it wrong by counting most included files...

Comment: You want the headers that are not going to change (or are going to change the least).  Any changes to the headers included in the pre-compiled header file will cause  all the .cpp files that include the pre-compiled header file to be recompiled.  So system headers; external libraries; your stable libraries are all good candidates.

Comment: My project sped up its compile time by 10% by getting rid of precompiled headers.  Make sure you carefully measure.

Comment: Trust no one. If it's important, profile.

Comment: I see. Ok thank you!